# Repository manager receives the wrong connection string in .net core

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, repository-pattern

I am developing a .Net 8.0 application, using Repository pattern and database first approach.

Program.cs file:

```
builder.Services.ConfigureRepositoryManager();
builder.Services.ConfigureSqlContext(builder.Configuration);
```

ServiceExtensions.cs file:

```
public static void ConfigureRepositoryManager(this IServiceCollection services)
{
        services.AddScoped<IRepositoryManager, RepositoryManager>();
}

public static void ConfigureSqlContext(
    this IServiceCollection services,
    IConfiguration configuration
)
{
    var conString = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(configuration.GetConnectionString("sqlConnection"));
    conString.UserID = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MSSQLServerUser");
    conString.Password = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MSSQLServerPassword");

    services.AddDbContext<RepositoryContext>(options =>
    {
        options.UseSqlServer(conString.ConnectionString);
    });
}
```

The connection string inside `ConfigureSqlContext` method gets updated with username and password, meaning the `conString.ConnectionString` is exactly correct. But on Repository instantiation, it receives the connection string defined inside `appsettings.json` file.

RepositoryManager.cs file:

```
public RepositoryManager(RepositoryContext context)
{
    _context = context;

    _appointment = new Lazy<IAppointmentRepository>(
        () => new AppointmentRepository(_context)
    );
}
```

In this class, the _context has wrong connection string.

I am trying to exclude the username and password from connection string, whether in development or in production. As MS suggests, there are multiple ways such as user secrets, but I couldn't make it work. It only works if I include the username and password inside connection string in `appsettings.json` file.